# LUbuntu 20.04 and tmporary user like guest?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, guest-session, sddm

How can I enable a restricted user where everything is reset after logout? Note: User is used for web-browsing so security is definitely a topic for me. In case user accesses maicious sites everything should be undone after logout and this user should operate like in a sandbox.

Previous LUbuntu versions came with LightDM as ad DM where you could set up a guest account according to these steps:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-guest-session-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

- How can I configure a temporary user with LUbuntu's default SDDM? (I don't care if user is requried to enter password or not)
- In case there is no solution with SDDM and I need to step back to LightDM: Is LightDM's guest account feature safe to use or are there still secuirty flaws?
- Can the installation easily be undone as written here? https://vitux.com/some-common-ubuntu-display-managers-and-how-to-switch-between-them/ or will it 'destroy' anything switching back to SDDM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/1091    `sddm` has no provision for a guest login.

Comment: I switched from GDM to LightDM and turned guest user on with no problem, (that I could see).

Comment: Is there any way to choose LightDM and sddm on startup e.g in the boot menu?

Answer (score 1):

### Add a Guest User to Ubuntu 20.04

- Install **lightdm**:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install lightdm
  ```
- At popup select lightdm as display manager.
- After install run:

  ```
    sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
  ```
- Change: allow-guest=true.
- On next boot there will be a guest user, no changes will be saved during the session.
- The administrator may change settings and add programs.
- I was able to switch back to GDM.

I am not sure if the reports of 17.04 Gnome being unconfined when in a guest session, still applies.

[Customize Guest Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession)

Comment: Failed to start session (for user/pass and for guest) after changing to lightdm. How can I fix this?

Comment: **edit** works now after I changed desktop environment to lubuntu Desktop